# CS50 mario program (pair of pyramids), why do I get an extra space etc?

Tags: python, cs50

I want to ask the user for pyramid height. For a height of 4, I want to print this: Two sets of pyramid separated by two spaces, with the requested height.

```
   #  #
  ##  ##
 ###  ###
####  ####
```

I have the following code:

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
            if 1 <= value <= 8:
                return value
        except ValueError:
            pass


def main():
    height = get_int("Height: ")
    for row in range(height):
        spaces = height - row - 1
        hashes = row + 1
        print(" " * spaces, "#" * hashes, end="")
        print("  ", end="")
        print("#" * hashes, " " * spaces)

main()
```

Output:

```
sentimental-mario-more/ $ python mario.py
Height: 8
        #  #        
       ##  ##       
      ###  ###      
     ####  ####     
    #####  #####    
   ######  ######   
  #######  #######  
 ########  ######## 
sentimental-mario-more/ $ check50 cs50/problems/2024/x/sentimental/mario/more
Connecting.......
Authenticating...
Verifying......
Preparing.....
Uploading.......
Waiting for results............................
Results for cs50/problems/2024/x/sentimental/mario/more generated by check50 v3.3.11
:) mario.py exists.
:) rejects a height of -1
:) rejects a height of 0
:( handles a height of 1 correctly
    expected ""#  #"", not "" #  # ""
:( handles a height of 2 correctly
    expected "" #  #"\n"##  ...", not ""  #  #  "\n" ..."
:( handles a height of 8 correctly
    expected ""       #  #"\...", not ""        #  # ..."
:( rejects a height of 9, and then accepts a height of 2
    expected " #  #\n##  ##\...", not "  #  #  \n ## ..."
:) rejects a non-numeric height of "foo" 
:) rejects a non-numeric height of ""
```

Even though the output looks like what I want, it doesn't pass the checks. It looks like I have some unwanted spaces in the output, but I am not able to figure out where.

Comment: The output _tells_ you what's wrong. Examine those cases.

Comment: It looks like there is an extra space before and after. But I do not know how that extra space crept in

Comment: Going forward, probably notice that you get a preview of what your post will look like below the editing pane. If your screen is wide enough, you also get a help button at the right of the editor's menu strip, with a link to the full [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: apologies. I have edited the question. I need to print two sets of pyramids seperated by two spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Comment: `"\n".join(f"{'#' * row:>{height}}  {'#' * row}" for row in range(1, height + 1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagnostics tell you what's wrong. It wants one space less than you print before the hashes, and no spaces after (they are unnecessary, as the screen is already blank by default).

However, the reason for the extra space is <del>nontrivial. You'll find  that `" " * 0` produces one space, not zero.</del>  *that the comma after `" " * 0` in the `print` arguments always supplies one space.*

The fix for that is to break out the printing of spaces, and make it conditional.

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
            if 1 <= value <= 8:
                return value
        except ValueError:
            pass  # or perhaps continue

def pyramids(height):
    for row in range(height):
        spaces = height - row - 1
        hashes = row + 1
        # conditional spaces
        if spaces:
            print(" " * spaces, end="")
        print("#" * hashes, end="")
        print("  ", end="")
        print("#" * hashes)  # no trailing spaces

def main():
    height = get_int("Height: ")
    pyramids(height)

main()
```

I also refactored the pyramid printing into a separate function; that's the only part here which would make sense to `import` from a script which needs this functionality, so that's more or less by definition the "function" you should have.

Demo: https://ideone.com/RS7IPq

Outside of your assignment, a better design would be to accept the number as a command-line argument instead of requiring interactive prompting, but let's not go there now.

Comment: Now that it's a separate function, perhaps it would also make more sense to do the range checking inside `pyramids`, so that it can return a range error if you call it with a number outside the accepted range.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood. Can you please tell me why CLI is better. I read it is better for batch processing. Is that why ?

Comment: Requiring interaction in a script means it's harder to call from other scripts. If you have a shell script which needs to print a pyramid, it's convenient to be able to say `python pyramids.py 5` rather than something (slightly) complex and brittle like `echo 5 | python pyramids.py`. But having the functionality in a function you can `import` is already an improvement; then you can write your own simple wrapper like `python -c 'from pyramids import pyramids; pyramids(5)'`

Comment: Updated the explanation. I don't know what I was thinking; but [thanks to MisterMiyagi in the Python chat room for setting me straight.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/57089788#57089788)

Answer (score -1):

Consider creating a function that generates a string representation of the pyramid instead of just printing directly, since this makes unit testing a lot easier since you don't need to mock `sys.stdout` (yikes ):

```py
"""Command-line utility for printing a Mario-style pyramid for cs50."""


def get_int_input(prompt: str, minimum: int = 0, maximum: int = 100) -> int:
  """Repeatedly asks user for int input with given prompt until within required range.

  Args:
    prompt: The message shown to the user asking them to input a value.
    minimum: The minimum integer value allowed to be entered. Defaults to 0.
    maximum: The maximum integer value allowed to be entered. Defaults to 100.

  Returns:
    An integer value provided by the user within the range: [minimum, maximum].
  """
  while True:
    try:
      x = int(input(prompt))
      if minimum <= x <= maximum:
        return x
    except ValueError:
      print('Error: Enter an integer, try again...')


def get_mario_pyramid(height: int, gap: int = 2) -> str:
  """Generates a string representation of a Mario-style pyramid for a specified height.

  Args:
    height: The height of the pyramid, which determines the number of rows.
    gap: The gap between the two halves of the pyramid. Defaults to 2.

  Returns:
    A string representing the complete pyramid.
  """
  pyramid = []
  for row in range(1, height + 1):
    leading_spaces = ' ' * (height - row)
    blocks = '#' * row
    pyramid.append(f'{leading_spaces}{blocks}{" " * gap}{blocks}')
  return '\n'.join(pyramid)


def main() -> None:
  """Entry point for the command line tool."""
  pyramid_height = get_int_input(prompt='Height: ', minimum=1, maximum=8)
  print(get_mario_pyramid(pyramid_height))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: No disagreement, but I didn't want to take it that far with a beginner question.

Comment: I'm like so close to Python readability at work; just practicing :) 
The reviewers for Python are even more pedantic than C++. Everything needs docstrings, etc...